# Vertx POST HttpClientRequest with body parameter

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I have to implement a Vertx POST request. Via Postman, the request is done as shown in the following picture:

[image]

The tricky part is that the server expects the key "upgrade_file" for the body. I could not find out how to do that with Vertx. This is what I have so far:

```
Buffer bodyBuffer = Buffer.buffer(body); // body is byte[]
HttpClientRequest request = ...
request.handler( response -> ...
request.end(bodyBuffer);
```

How can I set "upgrade_file" as the key for the body?

Comment: Try this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/RNQ6NY65nII

Comment: thanks, this was it

Answer (score 0):

Use a WebClient instead of the HTTP client, it provides dedicated support for submitting forms.

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
```

or if you already have created an http client:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.wrap(httpClient);
```

Then create the form data as map and send the form using a the right content type

```
MultiMap form = MultiMap.caseInsensitiveMultiMap();
form.set("upgrade_file", "...");

// Submit the form as a multipart form body
client.post(8080, "yourhost", "/some_address")
      .putHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
      .sendForm(form, ar -> {
        //do something with the response
      });
```

More example see https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send files, the simplest way is using the `sendMultipartForm` method of [Vertx WebClient](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/).

Create a `Multipartform` firstly.

```java
MultipartForm form = MultipartForm.create()
  .attribute("imageDescription", "a very nice image")
  .binaryFileUpload(
    "imageFile",
    "image.jpg",
    "/path/to/image",
    "image/jpeg");
```

Then invoke `WebClient.sendMultipartForm(form)` to send the request.

The generic Vertx HttpClient is a low-level API, you should searialize the form data into a string or buffer, the format is similar to [this example file in Vertx GraphQL testing codes](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web-graphql/src/test/resources/multipleUpload.txt). Then send the buffer to the server side.